# Custom web page and javascript routine running in the background

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

The Dynamics documentation is just awful and I couldn't find an answer to this simple question:

**In the web version of the CRM, is it possible to register a web page that can be toggled by the user and that itself has an internal state (updated regularly by an interval set with `setInterval`) that will persist even if the users closes the page (not the entire CRM, just the sub-page)?**

We need the user to provide some information for a CTI integration, and this background process to keep alive the CTI session by polling an API while the user session is active. In addition, we need to reuse the component where the user provides the CTI information to be notified if the session fails and restore it or close it if necessary. The real purpose for this is to make a screen pop (push content information about the incoming call to the agent) which I know can be done using [Xrm.Utility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602956.aspx), although doing it with a REST API method would be much better, [RouteTo Aciton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/mt607729.aspx) looks like the best method to do this, but I'm not sure it will proactively show the item in the user's browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this question is as simple as you suggest, it seems relatively complicated, and involves an integration. I'm not suprised the Dynamics documentation doesn't provide an answer for this specific and unique scenario.

I don't believe there is any single feature within Dynamics that will meet this requirement.

You could use a [HTML web resource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309536(v=crm.8).aspx) or a web page from a seperate web site [iframed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328034.aspx) into CRM. I think the possible use of these depends on your expected user experience; I believe the user would need to have the page loaded at all times showing these controls (e.g. user is looking at a dashboard) - I don't see how the controls could interact with the user client side otherwise. You could show the controls in multiple places however.

Xrm.Utility is one way to open a record, but it can also be done by [Open forms, views, dialogs, and reports with a URL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328483.aspx).

RouteToAction looks like it just adds a record into the user queue, the user would need to refresh the queues to see the changes. I don't believe there is any way for a server side REST API call to natively redirect the user.

You could add [JavaScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh771584.aspx) to do this, however you might struggle to add the JavaScript into every page of CRM.

Where I have worked on a CTI integration in the past (assuming you mean computer telephony integration), we always had some other component doing the screen pops - the client's all had a desktop app installed as part of the telephony solution.

Perhaps you could look into browser notifications, or a browser plugin?

Comment: Thanks! I needed someone with experience in integrating with Dynamics to shine some light. I'm trying to avoid installing a desktop app, and even if I do the problem of how to push to the agents browser persists. The browser plugin idea sounds really good though, I'm going to look into that.

Comment: Re: "Pushing to the agents browser", I just used a link to open CRM in a new tab with whatever I wanted to show, e.g. a phone call record.

Comment: Oh, just a link! That's great. You just saved us from going with an existing but ridiculously expensive solution, thanks James, have an amazing day!